# How group by date in Django

Tags: python, django, date, django-queryset

I have two dates.

`start_date = '2015/01/01'`
`end_date = '2015/04/01'`
My query return all orders between this two dates, but i need group by month.
So:

`data1: 2015/01/01 #start_date`
`data2: 2015/02/01`
`data3: 2015/03/01`
`data4: 2015/04/01 #end_date`

I need to chart with this data.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `itertools.groupby`, but careful as Django might cache the generator as a list and consume it.

```
from itertools import groupby
groupby(orders, lambda order : order.date.month)
```